# Get Device Owner profile information - Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, google-api

I would like to get informations concerning phone owner (nation, age, sex etc) to perform an automatic profiling.

I saw there are some opportunities:

- In Android there are these plugins:

https://github.com/vliesaputra/DeviceInformationPlugin

https://github.com/loicknuchel/cordova-device-accounts

they both allow to get account info, if everybody then have a google account, I'm wondering if is it possible to query google API to get public profile info, without requiring an authentication. Anybody has experiences in this kind of approach? Maybe also fb can be interrogated in this way

It seems that on iOS there isn't this kind of freedom

- Query for all contacts and get the one of the user, I think this is an hit or miss approach and don't know if there exists a way to know if a profile is surely the one of the owner.

Do you have any other experienced approach to perform a transparent user profiling with ionic? I'm wondering how to perform an useful approach both Android on and  on iOS

Thank you

Comment: Apple values privacy, so you can't get this information without permission. You need to just ask the user for this information, and make it optional

Comment: Thank you, do you know if exists any ionic plugin to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the following information from http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/device/

1. Platform
2. Version
3. UUID
4. Model